# Where do I put code that runs after a successful POST api call in node?

Tags: node.js, express

In node/express where do I put code that executes right after the a successful request. I would like to send an email after the call.

```
exports.postRequests = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {.... } = req.body;

        const post = await requests.save();
        return res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: 'ok',
                data: {
                    complete: post.complete,
                    id: post._id,
                },
            }); 
    } catch (err) {
        return errorResponse(res, 'Error occurred');
    }
};

//.then(emailSuccessMessage)....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.nextTick` or `setTimeout`

```js
exports.postRequests = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {.... } = req.body;

        const post = await requests.save();

        // already success here

        process.nextTick(() => {
            // emailSuccessMessage
        });

        return res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: 'ok',
                data: {
                    complete: post.complete,
                    id: post._id,
                },
            }); 
    } catch (err) {
        return errorResponse(res, 'Error occurred');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to listen to the request object event(the end event)

```js
exports.postRequests Middleware =  (req,res,nx)=>{
 req.on('end',postRequests)
 nx()
}

exports.postRequests = async (req, res) => {
        const {.... } = req.body;
        const post = await requests.save();
        return res
            .status(200)
            .json({
                status: 'ok',
                data: {
                    complete: post.complete,
                    id: post._id
                   }
               }); 
};
```